# Sorting strings containing dates with Python

Tags: python, string, date

I've got a bunch of strings in this format.

```
[24/4/2018 15:47:20] doctor's appt
[22/8/2016 11:47:09] workshop @ block 3
[24/4/2018 15:45:33] buy eggs
[31/2/2017 13:44:40] good day
[31/2/2017 13:44:35] flight
```

I'm trying to sort them in an ascending order according to the date and time using Python but I can't really figure it out. I'd really appreciate some help.

Edit: Hi guys thanks a lot for taking out your time to help me out here. Was able to solve it, appreciate it.

Comment: if they were in proper ISO format, you could just sort by string value

Comment: What's is the "bunch"? A list, a DataFrame, plain text in a file?

Comment: If they're in a list (or could be put in a list), [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#list.sort) admits an optional parameter `key` that [would allow](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) to use a function to extract the dates and convert them to datetimes. But maybe a different solution could be more suitable for a dataframe.

Comment: FYI: `31/2/2017` is not a valid date. There is no 31st of February.

Comment: @Matiiss hiya thanks a lot for the help! that really simplified things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring that `31/2/2017` is an invalid date, this should do it for you:

```
from datetime import datetime


lst = []
file = open('dates.txt', 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    formatStr = '[%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S]'
    datePart = ' '.join(line.split(' ')[0:2])
    dateobj = datetime.strptime(datePart, formatStr).date()
    lst.append((dateobj, line))

print(lst)
print(sorted(lst))
```

This assumes all of your dates are in a file called `dates.txt` one per line in the format you specified.

Comment: thanks a lot! that makes so much sense. and yea they're in a txt file so you really gave me a perfect solution. appreciate it.